# Можно ли написать «93 суток»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, счетный-оборот

1. Время нахождения в космосе второго спутника 93 суток.
2. Время нахождения в космосе второго спутника 93 дня.
3. Время нахождения в космосе второго спутника девяносто три дня.
4. Время нахождения в космосе второго спутника девяносто трое суток.

Какой верный вариант? Мы уже запутались и устали спорить.

Comment: Равно девяноста трём суткам, в течение (или "достигло") девяноста трёх суток :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что в счетных оборотах в именительном (и сходном с ним винительном) падеже количественные числительные не согласуются с именами существительными, а **управляют** ими.
При числительных два, три, четыре (а также в составных 22, 23, 24... 92, 93, 94) **существительные ставятся в родительном падеже единственного числа.**
Например, *тридцать два **портрета**, девяносто три **окна**, девяносто четыре **книги**.*

При сочетании составных числительных, оканчивающихся на два, три, четыре, с именами существительными, которые употребляются только во множественном числе (сутки, будни, ножницы, плоскогубцы, сани, щипцы), формы именительного и винительного падежа следует заменять **другим оборотом.**

[Сочетания количественных числительных с именами существительными](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html)

1. Правильно:
   **Время нахождения в космосе второго спутника — 93 дня.**
   Пропущено сказуемое "составляет", поэтому лучше поставить тире. Числительные больше десяти обычно записываются цифрами.
2. Правильно:
   **Второй спутник находился в космосе в течение 93 суток.**